# Batching Queries with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a way to batch independent (i.e. not dependent on a previous value) queries into a single request to the database in order to prevent round trips?

I intend use this to read data from several unrelated data models, so joins and views don't suffice.

Here's a very rough idea of what I'm attempting:

```
queries = {
  # What       Relation or SQL
  top_duck:    Duck.limit(1),          # We can't use first directly
  cow_count:   Cow.select('count(*)'), # We can't use count directly
  petals_lost: Flower.group_by('petals_lost').order_by('petals_lost')
                     .select('average(petals_lost) as average_petals_lost'),
  avg_score:   "select avg(score), stddev(score) from games"
}

bq = BatchQuery.new(queries)
# And in one trip...
bq.execute # => Hash<DB::Result> suffices for now; next step: typecasting
```

Comment: I don't know any SQL DB that supports it so would be surprised if Rails did.

Comment: MySQL [does](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html) and so does the Ruby client; I know Postgres supports asynchronous processing, but I'm not sure how to fire multiple queries to the DB at once.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that but still Google tells me it's not possible with Rails https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-core/sjSwOHGE4Oo